# Binding data from data base to view in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hello i have problem with binding my data from data base to my view in my application. I created a data base and imported it by Entity Framework, a have also ViewModel where i created connection to my data base. I want to take a random data from data base and show it in my View in labels. This is my code:

ViewModel

```
class TEST : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public object RandomWords()
    {
        TABUEntities baza = new TABUEntities();
        baza.HASLA.ToList();
        var a = baza.HASLA.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1);
        return a;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Model - Data Base

```
    public partial class TABUEntities : DbContext
{
    public TABUEntities()
        : base("name=TABUEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<HASLA> HASLA { get; set; }

}
```

and my View

```
<Window x:Class="Tabu.View.TEST"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tabu.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Tabu.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TEST" Height="600" Width="600">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:TEST/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding }" />
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding }" />
    <Label x:Name="label2" Content="{Binding }" />
    <Label x:Name="label3" Content="{Binding }" />

</Grid>
```

I dont know how to take a random element from my data base and bind it with view. In labels i want to put columns from my data base. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ItemsControl` such as a `DataGrid` to display the items in the EF table provided that you expose the source collection using a *public property* of the view model class:

```
public class TEST : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TEST()
    {
        SourceCollection = RandomWords();
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable SourceCollection { get; private set; }

    public object RandomWords()
    {
        TABUEntities baza = new TABUEntities();
        var a = baza.HASLA.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).ToList();
        return a;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="Tabu.View.TEST"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tabu.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Tabu.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TEST" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:TEST/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> is a possibility to show separated columns from database in labels or no?

If the change the type of the source collection property to `IList`, you could bind to an item in it using the indexer:

```
public IList SourceCollection { get; private set; }

<Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding SourceCollection[0].Property}" />
```

"Property" is the name of the property of the "HASLA" entity that you want to display in the `Label`.

Comment: is a possibility to show separated columns from database in labels or no?

Comment: Your `OnPropertyChanged` method can be safely changed to just `handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));` in later versions of C#. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/